# Powershell - Command works in interface but not within a script

Tags: powershell

Fairly new to scripting.
I have a very basic script which works fine within the ISE but when I run it within a file it doesn't.
Script:

```
#
# WPM Convert to Ascii.ps1
# Process to remove accented characters from a text file as they cause issues when importing to U4BW via GL07
# SP Jan 2019
#
# Parameters
#
$usefile    =$dir+"\"+'SPTEMP.txt'
$outfile    =$dir+"\"+'SPOUT.txt'

#
# Convert characters
#
Get-Content $usefile -replace 'a', 'A' |Set-Content $outfile
```

Simply converting characters in 1 file outputting to another.
Called from U4BW(Agresso) command being:-

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "c:\scripts\WPM Convert to Ascii.ps1" -infile "[File name]" -dir "[Directory]"
```

I have debugged all the parameters sent (infile and dir) and they are fine. Tried closing the file (outfile) beforehand.

I know this is probably a basic issue but I just can't see it.
Any help gratefully received!
Steve

Comment: How does it fail? Can you provide sample data and show what you expect to happen vs. what actually does happen?

Comment: What is the `-infile` parameter for? It is never used.

Comment: Thanks folks. infile is used elsewhere - I took out bits of the script that would just confuse plus the param line is actually there in my script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the following changes to your script.

Declare this at the top of your script so the `-dir` parameter in your call is actually recognized in the script:

```
param($dir)
```

Also, your replace command looks wrong, `-Replace` is not a valid parameter of `Get-Content`. You probably meant this?

```
(Get-Content $usefile) -replace 'a', 'A' | Set-Content $outfile
```

Final script (with some other minor improvements):

```
# WPM Convert to Ascii.ps1
# Process to remove accented characters from a text file as they cause issues when importing to U4BW via GL07
# SP Jan 2019

# Passed parameters
param (
    # The base directory path
    $dir
)

# Derived parameters
$usefile = Join-Path $dir "SPTEMP.txt"
$outfile = Join-Path $dir "SPOUT.txt"

# Replace characters
(Get-Content $usefile) -replace 'a', 'A' | Set-Content $outfile
```

Then call it like this:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "c:\scripts\WPM Convert to Ascii.ps1" -dir "[Directory]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what was said above, "replace" is not a parameter for get-content.

```
# WPM Convert to Ascii.ps1
# Process to remove accented characters from a text file as they cause issues when importing to U4BW via GL07
# SP Jan 2019
#

Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$usefile,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$outfile,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    $dir = $(Get-Location)
)


#
# Convert characters
#
(Get-Content $usefile) -replace 'a', 'A' |Set-Content $dir/$outfile
```

Comment: Thanks marsze/ConorT. Will try that.